# Escape characters in Freeswitch DSN string. (using maria_db)

Tags: freeswitch

I am using the maria_db module to connect freeswitch to a db backend.

This works fine, but I am now needing to connect to a database where there is an equals sign in the password.

How can I escape the equals in the dsn string?

I have tried the usual backslash and %3D but I always get authentication error.

Unfortunately I don't have any control over the password to set it without the equals sign.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having looked through the source code for this module, it is apparent that this isn't possible and requires a code change.